# ruby ajax request with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Is this proper when making an ajax request via ruby to use two params?

```
function drawIt(one_id, quest_id){
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/reer/porip?rn_id=" + one_id + "?two_id=" + quest_id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
  });
```

Comment: It's more correct to use Post and send a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

it's ok, however you have double `?` char in url. It should be:

`url: "/reer/porip?rn_id=" + one_id + "&two_id=" + quest_id,`

parameters in url are separated by `&`